# Chaining mongoose queries and return result in Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure if I'm having trouble because I don't understand JS or mongodb/mongoose.

Here's my current code:

```
/**
 * Fins all (biological) siblings of this person.
 * @returns {Array} Returns all the siblings as a list. If no siblings were found, returns an empty list.
 */
personSchema.methods.getSiblings = function () {
    const sibs = new Set();

    this.model('Person').findById(this.mother, function(err, mom) {
        mom.children.forEach((child) => { sibs.add(child); });
    });

    this.model('Person').findById(this.father, function(err, pa) {
        pa.children.forEach((child) => { sibs.add(child); });
    });

    console.log(sibs);
    return sibs;
}
```

I want this function to get all the children from this persons father and mother and return their ids as a list (effectively returning this persons biological siblings). Now the only thing that this function will ever return is an empty set. I think I understand why, and that is because the function does not wait for the queries to finish before returning. But how do I achieve this? I know I could use promises, but I want to add the fathers children even if the mother query returns an error...

Thanks for the help!

PS: Is there a nicer way to add all of the elements of a list to a set?

EDIT: I found a solution, but it's probably not optimal:

```
/**
* Finds all biological siblings of this person.
 * @param callback(sibs) the function to call when finished. Sets the sibs parameter of the callback function to a list
 * of sibling IDs or an empty list if no siblings were found.
 */
personSchema.methods.getSiblings = function (callback) {

const self = this;
const mId = this.mother;
const pId = this.father;
const sibs = [];

self.model('Person').findById(mId, "children", function (err, res) {
    if (!err)
        sibs.push(res.children);

    self.model('Person').findById(pId, "children", function (err, res) {
        if (!err)
            sibs.push(res.children);

        callback(_.uniqWith(sibs, _.isEqual));
    })
});
```

}

Comment: *"I know I could use promises, but I want to add the fathers children even if the mother query returns an error..."* so? catch the error.

Comment: try async await

Comment: @Thomas yes but then I'd have to add the father search both in "then" and in "catch".

Comment: Now you're getting close. Probably cleaner to get both the mother and father docs at once with a `find({_id: {$in: [mId, pId]}}, ...` query.